# Why Raphael js Graph doesn't work using .html()

Tags: jquery, raphael

I have a problem with my code. the code will display the table but not the graph the some.php is located in a folder named bin and the js are also located in that folder i really have no idea why it doesn't work when i try to look directly at some.php the graph is shown but when i click the button on the index.php no graph shows, i also tried to put bin/js/the js link but it results to a problem where i can no longer click button 2 can someone give me idea to why is this happening? or can someone give me an example i could work on

**the index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:red; margin:4px; }
  b { color:blue; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="action-button">
    <button id="1" value="1074">Button 1</button>
    <button id="2" value="1074">Button 2</button>
 </div>

  <div id="output"></div>

<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
      var attr = $(this).attr("id");
      var val = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "bin/some.php",
      data: { lookbookID: attr, type: val }
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#output").html(attr + ' - ' +  val + ' - ' + html);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**the some.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Raphaël · Analytics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
        <script src="js/raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/analytics.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
<?php 
echo "lookbookID: ".$_POST['lookbookID']." - "; 
echo " type: ".$_POST['type']
?>
        <table id="data">
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>11</th>
                    <th>12</th>
                    <th>13</th>
                    <th>14</th>
                    <th>15</th>
                    <th>16</th>
                    <th>17</th>
                    <th>18</th>
                    <th>19</th>
                    <th>19</th>
                    <th>20</th>
                    <th>22</th>
                    <th>23</th>
                    <th>24</th>
                    <th>25</th>
                    <th>26</th>
                    <th>27</th>
                    <th>28</th>
                    <th>29</th>
                    <th>30</th>
                    <th>31</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>54</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>79</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>44</td>
                    <td>44</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>83</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>91</td>
                    <td>52</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>78</td>
                    <td>70</td>
                    <td>68</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
           <div id="holder"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your approach

1. The ajax request retrieves an entire document, and you are attempting to inject that in the page. You shouldn't do that.
2. The jQuery .html method strips all of the JavaScript tags out for safety, so no js will execute.

You can probably test this theory by trying to use

```
$("#output")[0].innerHtml = attr + ' - ' +  val + ' - ' + html
```

Which may work in some browsers, but as I noted already, this is not valid. Since it is a full document you could try using an iframe, or modify the php to return just a snippet of html instead of a full document.